# nils found unwrapping Optional values in MKLocalSearch request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

Using iPhone6, Xcode 8.1, running iOS 10.1.1, executing the following Swift code, I am intermittently getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil unwrapping Optional value` in this simple code.

It Works without errors about 50% of the time which leads me to believe it is somehow related to the search call taking longer to complete as is suggested in some solutions to similar MapKit issues I've found. But the errors appear to occur inside the completion handler which doesn't contain optional values so I don't understand how I could be getting nil results.

The code snippets and console output are shown below. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var searchController:UISearchController!


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    //1
    print("Entered searchBarSearchButtonClicked")
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0] // both are type MKAnnotation
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    //2 make 1st search request
    print("Make 1st search request")
    let localSearchRequest1 = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest1.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    print("localSearchRequest1 initialized")

    let localSearch1 = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest1)
    localSearch1.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else  {

        //3 make annotation pin
        print("make annotation pin")
        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        print(searchBar.text ?? "searchBarText")
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        print(response!.boundingRegion.center.latitude)
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: response!.boundingRegion.center.latitude,           longitude:     response!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)
        self.coord1 = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate

        self.placeMark1 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.pointAnnotation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
        self.searchButtonClicked += 1

    }
})
```

> **** Console Log ****

```
Entered showSearchBar

Presented searchController

2016-11-24 22:07:41.409907 MapLocator 3 Match[1116:587460] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2016-11-24 22:07:41.420495 MapLocator 3 Match[1116:587460] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

Entered searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Make 1st search request

localSearchRequest1 initialized

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

2016-11-24 22:07:46.072037 MapLocator 3 Match[1116:587460] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws this error?

Comment: The line that appears to throw the error is "localSearch1.start" since the console log prints "localSearchRequest1 initialized" but never makes it to print "make annotation pin".

Answer (score 0):

Check your `response` object is not an optional value.

If you'd like to use `response!.boundingRegion.center.latitude`, using `guard let response = response else` to make sure `response` is not `nil`.

#### Update

I rewrite the code from initializing `localSearch1`, hope it could be helpful.

guard let localSearch1 = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest1) else {
        // localSearch1 is nil here
        return
    }

```
localSearch1.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        // Has an error, return
        print("Error occured in search:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    guard let response = response else {
        // response = nil, return
        print("No response data")
        return
    }

    // Make annotation pin
    self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text ?: ""
    self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: response.boundingRegion.center.latitude,
                                                            longitude: response.boundingRegion.center.longitude)
    self.coord1 = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
    self.placeMark1 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.pointAnnotation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)

    self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!) // I don't know whether this annotation is nil or not
    self.searchButtonClicked += 1
}
```

Also, you should know that in Swift, `self` can be omitted.

Comment: I gave this a try and changed my code to the following but still get intermittent nil unwrapping errors.<br/> guard

Comment: @davidwoj55 check other properties again. Prefer to use `var searchController:UISearchController?` when definition

Comment: I gave this a try as well but still getting the two fatal errors.

Comment: @davidwoj55 make sure everything are initialized!

Comment: Since I've bracketed my localSearch instantiation and localSearch1.start call with print statements and I get the nil errors before the print statement that follows them executes, doesn't that mean that the nils must be inside the search completion handler or the local Search1 constant? How else can I isolate these errors? Thank you.

Comment: @davidwoj55 I've updated my answer and hope this could be helpful to you.